# Creating Workflow Services using a Rehosted WF Designer

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

I am using Microsoft WF4.0 designer in a rehosted application. While I can generate workflows and save them to .xaml files, I want to be able to create workflow services of filetype (.xamlx) the same way I can in visual studio. Does anyone have any experience in doing this? I've looked around the internet and haven't found much. Any ideas are appreciated.

Thank you,
Siegfried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem:

workflowDesigner.Load(new WorkflowService{ /* property configuration */ } ).